# Selecting from a table the next values less than a table element

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, cursor, common-table-expression, priority-queue

I'm using SQL Server 2012.  I'm writing a weighted priority queue and I'm trying to pull out items from the queue based on a maximum weighting given as a table.

So I'll be given a table that looks something like the follow, specifying the number of items to pull out and the max weight value.  I want to pull out larger items first and then whittle down to the smaller ones.

**Selection table**

```
╔════════╦═══════════╗
║ weight ║ numValues ║
╠════════╬═══════════╣
║      1 ║         1 ║
║      2 ║         0 ║
║      3 ║         3 ║
╚════════╩═══════════╝
```

And another table that looks something like this

**item table**

```
╔══════╦══════╦════════╗
║ item ║ val  ║ weight ║
╠══════╬══════╬════════╣
║    1 ║ fish ║      1 ║
║    2 ║ goat ║      1 ║
║    3 ║ cat  ║      1 ║
║    4 ║ duck ║      3 ║
║    5 ║ pig  ║      2 ║
╚══════╩══════╩════════╝
```

What I need is to select from the selection table the values with the largest weights which fit into each of these categories.

I would want my results to look something like this

**Result**

```
╔══════╦══════╦════════╗
║ item ║ val  ║ weight ║
╠══════╬══════╬════════╣
║    1 ║ fish ║      1 ║
║    2 ║ goat ║      1 ║
║    4 ║ duck ║      3 ║
║    5 ║ pig  ║      2 ║
╚══════╩══════╩════════╝
```

Where the duck, pig, and fish satisfy getting 3 values for the weight of 3 and the goat satisfies the weight of 1 requirements.

Hope this makes a sense.

I know I could do something like this with cursors, however that seems like it would be slow and overkill.  I'm thinking it is possible to do it with a CTE, but I'm not sure how to approach it.

Thanks for the help.

*edit*
**A solution**

Using Jonathan's solution as a jumping off point, this is the beast I've crafted.  I think it should be "ok" but probably not that fast.

```
declare @selection TABLE 
    ([item] int, [val] varchar(4), [weight] int)
;

INSERT INTO @selection
    ([item], [val], [weight])
VALUES
    (1, 'fish', 1),
    (2, 'goat', 1),
    (3, 'cat', 1),
    (4, 'duck', 3),
    (5, 'pig', 2)
;
 declare @item TABLE 
    ([weight] int, [numValues] int)

INSERT INTO @item
    ([weight], [numValues])
VALUES
    (1, 1),
    (2, 0),
    (3, 3)

declare @potentialValues TABLE([item] int, [val] varchar(4), [weight] int, queueWeight int, [rn] int)
declare @maxRows INT = (SELECT SUM(numValues) FROM @item)
declare @largestQueueItem INT = (SELECT MAX(weight) from @item where numValues > 0)

;with CTE AS (
    Select 
        s.[weight] as itemWeight, 
        i.[weight] as queueWeight, 
        item, 
        val, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY i.weight ORDER BY s.weight desc) AS RN
    from @selection s
    FULL OUTER JOIN @item i ON s.weight <= i.weight
    where i.numValues > 0)
insert into @potentialValues ([item], [val], [weight], queueWeight, [rn])
select item, val, itemweight, queueWeight, rn from CTE
Where rn <= @maxRows


Declare @currentQueueItemSize INT = @largestQueueItem
while (@currentQueueItemSize > 0)
BEGIN
  DECLARE @count INT = (SELECT numValues from @item where weight = @currentQueueItemSize)
  ; WITH T
     AS (SELECT p.*
         FROM @potentialValues p
         WHERE p.queueWeight = @currentQueueItemSize
         ORDER BY p.rn
         OFFSET @count ROWS)
    DELETE FROM T

    DELETE p FROM @potentialValues p
    INNER JOIN @potentialValues pp 
    ON pp.item = p.item AND p.queueWeight < @currentQueueItemSize AND pp.queueWeight = @currentQueueItemSize

  SET @currentQueueItemSize = @currentQueueItemSize - 1
END

select item, val, weight from @potentialValues order by item
```

The good news is that I didn't use a cursor.  The bad news is that I used a while loop with a cte and a delete statement to pair down the table correctly.

Any way to get this thing in 1 maybe 2 passes?

Comment: You may find a CLR solution performs best. `Process each row in @selection (s) in descending order of weight and each row in @item (i) in descending order of weight

 If i.numValues == 0 then Move onto next i

 ElseIf s.weight > i.weight Move onto next s

 Else

  Output s, i.numValues--`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A solution**

Using Jonathan's solution as a jumping off point, this is the beast I've crafted.  I think it should be "ok" but probably not that fast.

```
declare @selection TABLE 
    ([item] int, [val] varchar(4), [weight] int)
;

INSERT INTO @selection
    ([item], [val], [weight])
VALUES
    (1, 'fish', 1),
    (2, 'goat', 1),
    (3, 'cat', 1),
    (4, 'duck', 3),
    (5, 'pig', 2)
;
 declare @item TABLE 
    ([weight] int, [numValues] int)

INSERT INTO @item
    ([weight], [numValues])
VALUES
    (1, 1),
    (2, 0),
    (3, 3)

declare @potentialValues TABLE([item] int, [val] varchar(4), [weight] int, queueWeight int, [rn] int)
declare @maxRows INT = (SELECT SUM(numValues) FROM @item)
declare @largestQueueItem INT = (SELECT MAX(weight) from @item where numValues > 0)

;with CTE AS (
    Select 
        s.[weight] as itemWeight, 
        i.[weight] as queueWeight, 
        item, 
        val, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY i.weight ORDER BY s.weight desc) AS RN
    from @selection s
    FULL OUTER JOIN @item i ON s.weight <= i.weight
    where i.numValues > 0)
insert into @potentialValues ([item], [val], [weight], queueWeight, [rn])
select item, val, itemweight, queueWeight, rn from CTE
Where rn <= @maxRows


Declare @currentQueueItemSize INT = @largestQueueItem
while (@currentQueueItemSize > 0)
BEGIN
  DECLARE @count INT = (SELECT numValues from @item where weight = @currentQueueItemSize)
  ; WITH T
     AS (SELECT p.*
         FROM @potentialValues p
         WHERE p.queueWeight = @currentQueueItemSize
         ORDER BY p.rn
         OFFSET @count ROWS)
    DELETE FROM T

    DELETE p FROM @potentialValues p
    INNER JOIN @potentialValues pp 
    ON pp.item = p.item AND p.queueWeight < @currentQueueItemSize AND pp.queueWeight = @currentQueueItemSize

  SET @currentQueueItemSize = @currentQueueItemSize - 1
END

select item, val, weight from @potentialValues order by item
```

The good news is that I didn't use a cursor.  The bad news is that I used a while loop with a cte and a delete statement to pair down the table correctly.

Any way to get this thing in 1 maybe 2 passes?

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @selection TABLE 
    ([item] int, [val] varchar(4), [weight] int)
;

INSERT INTO @selection
    ([item], [val], [weight])
VALUES
    (1, 'fish', 1),
    (2, 'goat', 1),
    (3, 'cat', 1),
    (4, 'duck', 3),
    (5, 'pig', 2)
;
 declare @item TABLE 
    ([weight] int, [numValues] int)

INSERT INTO @item
    ([weight], [numValues])
VALUES
    (1, 1),
    (2, 0),
    (3, 3)


;with CTE AS (
select T.item,t.val,tt.weight,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY TT.weight ORDER BY TT.weight)RN from @selection T 
FULL OUTER  JOIN @item TT
ON T.weight = TT.weight)
SELECT ITEM,
VAL,
COALESCE(weight,ROW_NUMBER()over(PARTITION BY weight ORDER BY item)+1,0)
 FROM CTE where ITEM IS NOT NULL AND RN <= 2
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to work.  You've set pig's weight to 22, which I wouldn't expect pig to be returned in that case.  Also it doesn't look like you are doing anything with numValues in @item.